# Unable to capture a correlate a value on a webpage using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am currently trying to record a webpage which includes bundled.js files which are used to build the webpage.

Tool: JMeter version 3.0

The issue is that when I record the page in JMeter and replay the page response does not include all the elements and therefore I am unable to correlate the values that I need to then pass to the next call.

What I have noticed is that if I attach a view results tree to the recorder the values that I am looking for are visible. So they are being captured during the record but not visible on the response when replaying.

I am thinking that the .js files are executed during page load and therefore not being captured and all it shows is the actual

Please help

Answer (score 0):

**JMeter does not run client-side JS code at all**. JS code is used for rendering on client side, while recording (and replay) in JMeter is done on HTTP level (communication level between client and server). It's the same level you'd see on Net tab in Developer tools of the browser. As far as recording/replay are concerned, those file will only be downloaded, and the client to server traffic they produce will be replayed. But nothing that runs purely on client side will be replayed. So if some magic/logic happens on client side (e.g. calculations, data transformation, etc within JS, which then is sent to the server), you have 2 options:

1. Duplicate the same logic /dynamic data using JMeter scripting functionality before sending an HTTP request. This is what most commonly people do.
2. Or another option is to use Selenium sampler and duplicate UI-level behavior, but that type of testing is quite limiting and only fits certain cases